# SAP B1 Error: (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT

Tags: c#, sapb1

I am getting an error when I open a SAP B1 form a second time, error is not thrown when I open the form the first time after running the addon.

Error message:

> SAP B1 Error: (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT

This is a b1f form built through Visual Studio.

The error gets thrown here:

```
if (pVal.FormTypeEx == "ContinuousProduction.LaminationSFGReceipt" && pVal.EventType == SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_FORM_VISIBLE && pVal.BeforeAction == false)
{
    if (EditText3.Value == string.Empty)  <-- Error gets thrown here
    {
        Button3.Item.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Button3.Item.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please add debug information

Comment: try restart SAP and visual studio, in debug does hovering over the edit text show as "nothing"?

Comment: @Praxiom, it shows "" ...basically null/empty/

Comment: looks like you are hitting the edittext before it has been initialized, is it added via the GUI form designer or via code?

Comment: @Praxiom It is added via the GUI form designer, b1f form in Visual Studio. Remember, the first time I open the form, no error. It happens on the 2nd and subsequent times I open the form.

Comment: RPC_E_SERVERFAULT is a very generic error which means the COM "server" (in this case probably an SAP process?) raised an exception (in its own process) or crashed, etc. and the RPC link has therefore failed. So COM informs its "clients" of that "server fault" issue. Of course, it may be something that you do that initially causes this, but in the end, it's the server's fault. You should contact the server's vendor. Sometimes, you can just swallow this fault and retry, or recreate the server (remove all references and create the COM object again).

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77837630/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) plagiariser.

Answer (score -1):

Even though your error comes from the server, check first if some safeguard checks in your client code would be enough:

```
// Event handler for form visibility
if (pVal.FormTypeEx == "ContinuousProduction.LaminationSFGReceipt" && pVal.EventType == SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_FORM_VISIBLE && pVal.BeforeAction == false)
{
    // Check if EditText3 is not null to prevent null reference exception
    if (EditText3 != null)
    {
        // Check if EditText3's value is empty or null
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EditText3.Value))
        {
            // Hide the button if EditText3 is empty
            Button3.Item.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Show the button if EditText3 has a value
            Button3.Item.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the case where EditText3 is null (e.g., log an error or take corrective action)
    }
}
```

You might at least capture the error on the client side.

Comment: You have an old (2008) [similar RPC error on `get_Value`](https://answers.sap.com/questions/5194179/exception-on-read-or-set-udf-document-lines-value.html) which is around Items.

Comment: Hmm, this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau Don't hesitate to post here an answer when you will find the solution.